# Edit file in Android 11 using react native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, storage

I have build an app to edit text using react native, it work well on android 7, now on android 11 it say "permission denied" may be due to android scoped storage  limitation, I've used react-native-fs and also react-native-scoped-storage but none work.
what I want is how to edit a file in android 11 using react-native.
file to edit inside "/storage/emulated/0/note/my_note.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether it's working in android 10 or not after that check whether you have added this line in your manifest file or not, if this line is not present then add this and try to run

```
<application
        ...
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/>
```

Comment: i am also using react-native-fs in android 11 and its working perfectly, i am using this version of library in my code "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0"

Comment: are you not able to select file or file is selecting successfully but getting issue in edit?

Comment: I have already do this     ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and also added 
` android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` but it does not work

Comment: on android 11, i can do nothing, even selecting the file using `RNFS.readFile(my_file_path,'utf8')`

Comment: if you are getting file path then try using this Platform.OS === "ios" ? path : `file://${path}`; in RNFS.readFile(my_file_path,'utf8') maybe this help

Comment: may be my bad, but I do not understand why should I verify if my platform is 'ios',

Comment: because if you didn't use check might be it cause issue in ios app, if you only require android app then no need for verify platform

Comment: yes I only require android app